# Accessing array in Python/Numba gives weird result

Tags: python, numpy, casting, numba

I'm trying to use numpy with numba but I'm getting weird results while trying to access or set some values to a numpy array of float using a float index converted to an int.
Check with this basic function.

```
@numba.jit("void(f8[:,::1],f8[:,::1])")
def test(table, index):
 x,y = int(index[0,0]), int(index[1,0)
 table[y,x] = 1.0
 print index[0,0], index[1,0], x,y
 print table
 print table[y,x]

table = np.zeros((5,5), dtype = np.float32)
index = np.random.ranf(((2,2)))*5
test(table, index)
```

**results:**

```
index[0,0] = 1.34129550525 index[1,0] = 0.0656177324359 x = 1 y = 0    
table[0,1] = 1.0 
table [[ 0.     0.     1.875  0.     0.   ]
       [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
       [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
       [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]
       [ 0.     0.     0.     0.     0.   ]]
```

Why do I get a 1.875 in my table and not a 1.0? This a basic example but I'm working with big array and it gives me a lot of error. I know i can convert index to *np.int32* and change *@numba.jit("void(f8[:,::1],f8[:,::1])")* to *@numba.jit("void(f8[:,::1],i4[:,::1])")* and that is working fine, but I would you like ton understand why this is not working.
Is it a problem while parsing the type from python to c++?

Thanks for you help

Comment: Isn't there a discrepancy between the f8 declaration in the jit and the initialization np.float32?
The 1.875 is not located at x=1.
BTW why is it tagged C++?

Comment: @Joky C++ tag was a mistake sorry. Yes it's working with np.float64.
But for a number like 1.0 should float 32 or float64 make a difference?

Comment: Since you tagged C++ ;) : The issue is that table is a pointer to double, pointing to an array of float. Writing a double in position 1 overlap position 3/4 for the floats (2 times larger) and the encoding of a double on top of two float does not make sense. BTW it is a guess since I don't know exactly what is the numba generated code. Edit: unutbu explained clearly below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [198]: np.float64(1.0).view((np.float32,2))
Out[198]: array([ 0.   ,  1.875], dtype=float32)
```

So when

```
table[y,x] = 1.0
```

writes a `np.float64(1.0)` into `table`, `table` views the data as `np.float32` and interprets it as a 0 and a 1.875.

Notice that the 0 shows up at index location `[0,1]`, and `1.875` shows up at index location `[0,2]`, whereas the assignment occurred at `[y,x] = [0,1]`.

You could fix the dtype mismatch by changing

```
@numba.jit("void(f8[:,::1],f8[:,::1])")
```

to

```
@numba.jit("void(f4[:,::1],f8[:,::1])")
```

---

These are the 8 bytes in `np.float64(1.0)`:

```
In [201]: np.float64(1.0).tostring()
Out[201]: '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?'
```

And when the 4 bytes `'\x00\x00\xf0?'` are interpreted as a `np.float32` you get 1.875:

```
In [205]: np.fromstring('\x00\x00\xf0?', dtype='float32')
Out[205]: array([ 1.875], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Great thanks. Maybe it's a stupid question but why this difference between np.float64 and np.float32?

Comment: `np.float64` represents a 64-bit (8-byte) float. `np.float32` represents a 32-bit (4-byte) float. `np.float(1.0)` occupies 8 bytes. If you write it into `table`, you are overwriting 8 bytes. When `table` is printed, it interprets its underlying data as 4-byte floats, so what you've written affects 2 values (floats) in `table`.

Comment: Ok I knew that float64 was 8 bytes and float32 4 bytes. But I thought the number of bytes was only changing the maximum number you could write. Not the way how the number was written. For example np.int32(1).tostring() gives'\x01\x00\x00\x00' and np.int64(1).tostring() gives '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' so even if float and integer is different, I thought np.float64 would give
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?'

Comment: If you enter `3FF0000000000000` into the form [here](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html) it will show you the 32bit and 64bit representations. The exponent field is of different lengths, so a different number of bits are required to be 1 to fill up the exponential field. For reference, here is the definition for IEEE754 [64bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) and [32bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) floating-point formats.